# Server Error in '/domain/website' Application

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, webserver, web-deployment-project

I am getting following error while i deployed the website..

```
Server Error in '/domain/website' Application.

Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I tried changing customErrors mode="Off"  But no Joy ..same error repeats ...

Moreover , GenericErrorPage.htm is missing is this causing the error?

Any helping hands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly because there is a syntax error in web.config. You could try replacing your current web.config with one that only contains this and see what happens:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Like I said it's possible the error is in the web.config. My suggestion eliminates any problems with the web.config

Comment: The problem could be with some other piece of configuration on the server. Without the customerrrors=off web.config file you'll never see what the actual error is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using dual web.config in your website. eg.

if you are using one web.config in /domain and another in /domain/website. You need to convert the /website as an application.

however, I would suggest you to log into the server and browse the page, you will be able to see the real issue. If you are unsure how to fix it. post it once. We might be able to help you.